# Wolfram Alpha "x = derivative x"

Tags: calculus, derivatives, wolfram-alpha

Asking Wolfram Alpha $x = \text{derivative } x$, I was expecting $e^x$, being that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, Wolfram Alpha however yields $x = 1$.

Is this stating that the derivative of a line that in its entirety has an infinite slope, also has an infinite slope?

Comment: As others are noting, W|A isn't properly interpreting your intent. [See here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/DifferentialEquations.html) for examples of how to enter differential equations into W|A. In particular, you should enter `x-x'=0` or `x=x'` to get the exponential solution you expect (with a multiplied constant, of course!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha interprets it as $x = x'(x)$, i.e. $x = \dfrac{dx}{dx} = 1$
It's nothing about slope.

Comment: In this context, does $x'$ not mean "the derivative of x"?

Comment: @alan2here It does - but it differentiates x with respect to x, so you get dx/dx, which is just 1.

Comment: Should I ask $x = d/dx(x)$? But $d/dx$ algebraically seems to simply to "inverse of $x$" as opposed to "derivative of $x$".

Comment: I think you should ask "y = dy/dx"

Comment: Ok, cool :) perplexingly seems to work. Thanks :) I strive to understand why.

Comment: @Alan: The d in d/dx isn't a variable by itself. That's just one of the ways write "derivative with respect to x".

Comment: Then, what? It's interpreting it as if it is variables by themsleves, having first interepreted it as a derivative?

Answer (score 1):

It's interpreting your question as "$x=\frac{{d}x}{dx}$", and $\frac{{d}x}{dx}$ is 1.